# Symfony - lexik jwt authentication - token not found

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am using lexik_jwt_authentication on my backend with simfony 3.3.
My problem is that the response when I try to do the login is:

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "JWT Token not found"
}
```

Also if I navigate my site the bundle told me to provide a token in all the pages. This is OK but this should not happen when I check for the login in "login_check", and in this case I am unable to generate a token.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

config.yml:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/private.pem'
    public_key_path:  '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/public.pem'
    pass_phrase:      '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'
    token_ttl:        3600

fos_user:
   db_driver: orm
   firewall_name: main
   user_class: ApiBundle\Entity\FosUser
   from_email:
      address: "%mailer_user%"
      sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

security.yml:

```
    firewalls:        
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            fr3d_ldap:  ~
            security: false
            form_login:
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false
            logout: true
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true

        api:
            pattern: ^/
            stateless: true
            provider: fos_userbundle
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            fr3d_ldap:  ~
            form_login:
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false
            logout: true
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
```

Comment: did you check this way https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#usage

Answer (score 0):

in your `security.yml` you need to specify into `access_control` that login isn't authenitcated fully like this:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried that but nothing has changed.